# Puppeteer: wait for element to be deleted

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I starting to work with Puppeteer in order to generate screenshots from ads on my website. When the ads are loading there is placeholders which matches the following selector div.adm-ad-loading.

I want to wait until **all** these divs are deleted (these div are not hidden, but deleted) to take the screenshot.

I read the documentation talking about waitForSelector function but it doesn't match my needs. I then found the waitForFunction but it doesn't seems to work for now:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs');

const config = require('config/puppeteer_conf.json');

if (fs.existsSync(config.OUTPUT_PATH)) {
  fs.unlinkSync(config.OUTPUT_PATH);
}

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: "new"});
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 2000 });

  await page.goto(config.TARGET_URI);

  const selector = 'div.adm-ad-loading';
  const watchDog = page.waitForFunction(
    selector => document.querySelector(selector) == null,
    {},
    selector
  );

  await watchDog;

  await page.screenshot({ path: config.OUTPUT_PATH });

  await browser.close();
})();
```

My goal is to wait until I'm sure all the ads are loaded (which is when all the placeholders are deleted).

Comment: This code looks fine to me. Do you need to wait for the selector to be visible before waiting for it to disappear? What site are you automating? A runnable example would help illustrate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach of using `waitForFunction` to pause the action until all `div.adm-ad-loading` elements are removed is smart. However, you may need to tweak it a bit to perfectly meet your requirements.

The thing is, ad placeholders may not all vanish at the same moment – they can disappear one after the other as each ad finishes loading. This could mean that the `waitForFunction` could consider its job done after spotting the disappearance of the first placeholder, not sticking around to ensure the rest follow suit. To ensure that your screenshot captures the page only after every last placeholder has left the scene, your function needs to patiently wait until the coast is clear of all such divs.

Let me offer you a refined version of your function that’s fine-tuned to wait until the stage is completely free of any `div.adm-ad-loading` instances:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs');
const config = require('config/puppeteer_conf.json');

if (fs.existsSync(config.OUTPUT_PATH)) {
    fs.unlinkSync(config.OUTPUT_PATH);
}

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 2000 });
    await page.goto(config.TARGET_URI);

    // Wait until no divs with the class 'adm-ad-loading' are present in the DOM.
    await page.waitForFunction(() => !document.querySelector('div.adm-ad-loading'));

    await page.screenshot({ path: config.OUTPUT_PATH });
    await browser.close();
})();
```